# How to define the scales in a biorthogonal, dyadic Discrete Wavelet Transform in Python

Tags: image-processing, python, wavelet

I am sorry if this has been discussed before but I could not find any answer.

I am trying to implement an algorithm that I found in a paper which asks for a biorthogonal, dyadic DWT with scales 1 and 2 using 'algorithme a trous'. I use PyWavelets' Stationary Wavelet Transform function to achieve this but I could not find any way to specify scales.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me about this either by using Pywavelets or any other library.

In below link's page 25, you can find the functions provided by PyWavelets.

[Link](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pywavelets/v0.5.2/pywavelets.pdf)